# React context is undefined when the children are rendered using this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a really annoying behaviour in React. I would like to pass the context from the parent component to the child component using `getChildContext`. Everything works fine as long as I don't use `{this.props.children}` in the render function. If I do so, the context of the children component is undefined.

I am attaching a code example that reproduce this behaviour.  I can't figure out why the `bar` filed of context of the component `Baz` is `undefined`.

```
var Baz = React.createClass({
 contextTypes: {
   bar: React.PropTypes.any
 },
 render: function() {
   console.log(this.context);
   return <div />;
 }
});

var Bar = React.createClass({
 childContextTypes: {
   bar: React.PropTypes.any
 },

 getChildContext: function() {
   return {
     bar: "BAR"
   };
 },

 render: function() {
   return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
 }
});

var Foo = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
   return <Bar>
      <Baz />
   </Bar>;
 }
});

console.log(React.version);

React.render(<Foo />, document.body);
```

Console Output:

```
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `BAR`) for key (bar) while mounting Baz (see: http://fb.me/react-context-by-parent)
Inline JSX script:10 Object {bar: undefined}
```

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3h7pxnkx/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So it appears that all of the components get the child context of where they are created.  In this case `<Baz />` is created as a part of `Foo`, so it gets the child context from `Foo`, which is why it's undefined.

Couple of options.

1) Set the child context on `Foo`.
2) Recreate the `<Baz>` child in `Bar`.  You can do this with cloneWithProps.

```
render: function() {
   console.log(this);
   return React.addons.cloneWithProps(this.props.children)
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crob611/3h7pxnkx/2/

Issue on react project discussing it: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3392

Comment: Just worth noting that, as the warning indicates, the plan is that this behavior will be changing in React v0.14 so that `Baz` will get its context from its parent `Bar` instead of its owner `Foo`.